# Qt attribute(property) binding to QLabel

Tags: c++, qt

Hi I'm pretty new in Qt.

Can I binding class attribute(or property) to QLabel text?
For example,

```
class Dog{
    string name;
}

QLabel lbl;
```

When I change dog's name, I'd like to change lbl.text

Comment: your code should be tagged to c++ so you can get the right attention from developers....

Comment: In your title you refer to PyQt, but your code uses C++. Please clarify what you need and for what language.

Comment: Qt signals are working only between `QObjects` so since `Dog` is not `QObject` you can't do it. And from first look on `Dog` class it should stay like this (should not inherit `QObject`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qt things that you are talking about are the territory of signals and slots. Good way to do:

Dog.h:

```
#ifndef DOG_H
#define DOG_H

#include "QObject"

class Dog: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void setDogsName(const QString &name)
    {
        m_Name = name;
        emit dogsNameChanged(name);
    }
signals:
    void dogsNameChanged(const QString &name);

private:
    QString m_Name;
};

#endif // DOG_H
```

`Q_OBJECT` [macro](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT) is needed for signal/slot connections to work (and it's got to be in `private` section, e.g. above `public:` here). Code's got to be in a separate .h file (!).

main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QLabel lbl;
    Dog dog;
    QObject::connect(&dog, &Dog::dogsNameChanged, &lbl, &QLabel::setText);
    dog.setDogsName("TEST");
    lbl.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Result: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQoeG.png).

Read about connections in Qt [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/signalsandslots.html).

Comment: I'm not convinced that `Dog` should become a `QObject`.